# Why do I get the server name instaid of the UID

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I'm trying to access my SQL Server database using a service account. I'm putting the information as so:

```
<add name="conn" 
     connectionString="Data Source=mtl1sqlitmp3\mtl1sqlitmp3;Initial Catalog=IT_Ops; Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=service account; Password=password" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For some reason, it always gives me usermane of the server.

Why is that?

What do I have to change to make the appropriate connection?

Thanks,

Comment: which sql? MYSQL/MS SQL Server?

Comment: It is MS sql server and I host on a Server 2012 r2 IIS 8.5

Comment: Is the name of your server and your database both "mtl1sqlitmp3"?

Comment: `Integrated Security=SSPI` says "use windows login information" and, unfortunately, doesn't cause an error if you also supply a user id/password, despite the fact that they'll be ignored.

Comment: I thought that Windows Security is used if the User ID and Password are absent, and use the User ID and Password if they are present

Comment: Yes I can connect from my dev laptop. But not once published on the server. However I don' know if it uses my laptop login or the service account to connect.

Answer (score 4):

You specified `Integrated Security=SSPI` in your connection string, presumably without realizing what that meant. As explained in the [`ConnectionString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=VS.100).aspx) documentation (among many other places):

> If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.

(Note that "`SSPI`" means the same thing as "`True`")

Answer (score 3):

```
 Integrated Security=SSPI
```

This means you are requesting integrated security. You will authenticate with the service account of your process (be it ASP.Net pool if such) *or* an  impersonated context if impersonating and constrained delegation is enabled. Connection string user name and password are ignored if integrated security is used.

You should use integrated security not user name and password, so you better focus on getting this working properly (set up your process to work as the appropriate service account and grant the necessary permissions to this account). Remember that passwords in connection strings in config are likely leaked.

Comment: What are the best practices for using service accounts to connect to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my issue, I've kept the `Integrated Security=SSPI` and removed the UID and PW from the connection string.

Instead, I've configured my service account and password in the Identity option of the Application Pools of my website in IIS.

It now works as expected.

Thanks for your help